# Javascript - Why is input value missing a character?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get this script to autofill another field while the original field is being filled in. But the second field loses the last character of its value. Any ideas why?

```
Here is the code... 

<input type="text" class="first" placeholder="type here">
<input type="text" class="second" placeholder="here it is the reuslt">

$(".first").on('keydown',function(){
$(".second").val($(this).val());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fmdwv/1/

Comment: Because at the time `keydown` fires, the value of `input` has not been changed yet.

Comment: I am having a difficult time understanding this question. Would if be possible to correct the spelling and grammar?

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Comment: like @Teemu mentioned, your trigger needs to be bound to `keyup` not `keydown`

Answer (score 2):

The `keydown` event fires before the `value` is updated, so when you read it, you get the `value` before it has been changed by the key being pressed.

Use the `input` event instead (that will also fire after a paste).

```js
$(".first").on('input', function() {
  $(".second").val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="first" placeholder="type here">
<input type="text" class="second" placeholder="here it is the reuslt">
```

Answer (score 0):

The **onkeydown** event occurs when the user is pressing a key

The **onkeyup** event occurs when the user releases a key

The **onkeypress** event is not fired for all keys (e.g. ALT, CTRL, SHIFT, ESC) in all browsers. To detect only whether the user has pressed a key, use the onkeydown event instead, because it works for all keys.

**in your case** **onkeydown** it execute function first .so on execution values inside input is not updated with pressed key value so it fires before value inserted

checkout this [example](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onkeydown)

```js
$(".first").on('keyup',function(){
$(".second").val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="first" placeholder="type here">
<input type="text" class="second" placeholder="here it is the reuslt">
```